# Galaxy Nexus NFC Verizon

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, verizon, nfc

Does the Galaxy Nexus have NFC on Verizon? I remember reading about the phone being delayed because competing carriers wanted to avoid Google Wallet and that some carriers had even disabled the NFC chip to avoid that.

But I don't know about the outcome of that situation.

Do all US versions of the Galaxy Nexus have NFC enabled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Verizon GNex has NFC, it just doesn't have Google Wallet pre-installed. [It's pretty trivial to sideload it, though](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57344873-285/get-google-wallet-on-the-samsung-galaxy-nexus-without-rooting/), and it's worked just fine the 2 times I used it.

Another thing to note here is that the NFC antenna is actually on the battery, not in the device itself. This means that if you get an extended battery you need to make sure it has an NFC antenna in it as well, otherwise it won't work.

The T-Mobile USA and Sprint versions haven't actually been released yet, so I guess there's no guarantee on those at this point. Sprint supported NFC and Google Wallet for the Nexus S 4G, though, so I can't imagine they'd stiff the GNex. For T-Mobile you could just get the existing GSM version and it should work fine since it's pentaband HSPA+ (it should work on AT&T for the same reason, though you wouldn't get their LTE service).